# c# Cast string as IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, string, generics, casting, ienumerable

I have this function:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> UniqueInOrder<T>(IEnumerable<T> iterable)  
{  
    return iterable.Distinct();  
}
```

This works with any IEnumerable except with a string, I must test it with this call:

```
Assert.AreEqual("ABCDAB", UniqueInOrder("AAAABBBCCDAABBB"));
```

The assert fail:

```
Expected is <System.String>, actual is <System.Linq.Enumerable+<DistinctIterator>c__Iterator10`1[System.Char]>
  Values differ at index [4]
```

I also tried something like:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> UniqueInOrder<T>(IEnumerable<T> iterable)
{
    return "abc";
}
```

But I have a compiler error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>'
```

How is possible that I can call the function with a string but I can not return a string? The type is still the same IEnumerable< T >

Any idea?
Thank you!

EDITED:
Distinct() was wrong, I changed to this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> UniqueInOrder<T>(IEnumerable<T> iterable)
{
    List<T> result = new List<T>();
    foreach (var c in iterable.ToList())            
        if (result.LastOrDefault() == null || !result.LastOrDefault().Equals(c))
            result.Add(c);              
    return result;
}
```

Now all the tests are passing! Thanks!

Comment: `Distinct()` won't return more than one of the same letter, so why do you expect that return value? As for the second question, you can't return a string from that method, because a string only fulfills `IEnumerable<char>`, not any other type `T`.

Comment: `UniqueInOrder` is fine. `Assert.AreEqual()` expects the string.

Comment: _"How is possible that I can call the function with a string but I can not return a string"_ You are mixing up parameters with return types. A string is `IEnumerable<char>` but it's not convertible to any kind of `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @Matthew a string [definitely is an `IEnumerable<char>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx), but it's not an `IEnumerable<T>` for any T other than `char`.

Comment: Either way `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerable<char>` aren't equatable.

Comment: @MatthewWhited: A `string` can be assigned to `IEnumerable<char>`.

Comment: Apart from the type issue, your assertion will also fail because the method does not what you expect: it will return `ABCD` instead of `ABCDAB`.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper But an `IEnumerable<char>` (what the method returns) can´t be assigned nor compared to a string

Answer (score 7):

Actually a string is a collection of characters, thus when you use `UniqueInOrder("AAAABBBCCDAABBB")` you actuall call `UniqueInOrder<char>`, instead of `UniqueInOrder<string>`. Thus the return-value of the method will also be `IEnumerble<char>`, not just string.

So you should compare the methods return-value with a collection of characters, e.g.:

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new[] { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A' 'B', 'Ä' }, UniqueInOrder(...));
```

or easier:

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected.ToCharArray(), UniqueInOrder(...));
```

But even then your test will fail as `Distinct` will filter out all duplicates.

When you want to check if two sequences are completely identical you may use `SequenceEqual` instead:

```
var equal = firstColl.SequenceEqual(second);
```

EDIT: Obviously you´re trying to remove all just the doubled characters in a sequence. You may use this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> UniqueInOrder<T>(IEnumerable<T> iterable) where T : IEquatable<T>
{
    T previous = default(T);
    foreach (var t in iterable)
    {
        if (!t.Equals(previous))
            yield return t;
        previous = t;
    }
}
```

Now you can call it and compare it with your expected output, e.g.:

```
var actual = new String(UniqueInOrder("AABBCCDDAABB").ToArray());
var expected "ABCDAB";
Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
```

Comment: But then the test still won't pass, because `Distinct()` doesn't care about order, it'll return `{ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' }`...

Comment: "the return-value of the method will also be IEnumerble<char>, not just string." - a `string` *is* an expression of type `IEnumerable<char>`.

Comment: I believe it should be `if (!t.Equals(previous))`

Answer (score 2):

Himbrombeere has explained why the assertion fails because of the type issue. But it will also fail because `Distinct` does not what you expect. It will remove all duplicate letters, not only those which are consecutive. So  it will return `ABCD` instead of `ABCDAB`.

This will do what you want and the assertion will pass:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> UniqueInOrder<T>(IEnumerable<T> iterable, EqualityComparer<T> comparer = null)
{
    if (comparer == null) comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    bool first = true;
    T lastItem = default(T);
    foreach(T thisItem in iterable)
    {
        if (first || !comparer.Equals(thisItem, lastItem))
        {
            first = false;
            yield return thisItem;
        }
        lastItem = thisItem;
    }
}
```

---

```
Assert.AreEqual("ABCDAB", String.Conat(UniqueInOrder("AAAABBBCCDAABBB")));
```

Answer (score 1):

As to the first part of your question, the reason your assertion is failing is because of the `.Distinct()`

When calling

```
UniqueInOrder("AAAABBBCCDAABBB");
```

This method:

```
private IEnumerable<T> UniqueInOrder<T>(IEnumerable<T> iterable)    
{
    return iterable.Distinct();
}
```

will return `{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'}`

However this method:

```
private IEnumerable<T> RemovesDupesInOrder<T>(IEnumerable<T> iterable)
{
    List<T> result = new List<T>();

    T last = default(T);
    iterable.ToList().ForEach(t =>
    {
        if (t.Equals(last) == false)
        {
            last = t;
            result.Add(t);
        }
    });

    return result;
}
```

would return `{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B'}`

BEWARE: `t.Equals(last)` may or may not do what you expect with reference types.

Comment: `.ToList().ForEach(...)` will loop your data twice... use a normal `foreach` statement.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. It's a great point. I'm going to leave my code as it is. Hopefully people will read your comment and it will be a good reminder.

Answer (score 0):

`UniqueInOrder("AAAABBBCCDAABBB")` returns `"ABCD"`, as these are the distinct characters in the string. This is not equal to `"ABCDAB"`, and the difference is in the 5th character (or character 4 in code terms, since am `IEnumerable` is 0-indexed).

This is exactly what the assert fail is telling you. The characters differ at the element in the enumerable with index 4. Specifically, in the second argument that index doesn't exist. `Assert.AreEqual("ABCD", UniqueInOrder("AAAABBBCCDAABBB"))` will work fine

You get a compiler error in the `return "abc"` case because `"abc"`, a string, is not a generic `IEnumerable`. If you passed in an `IEnumerable<int>` the types would be incompatible so it has to be a compiler error